# Bin Packing on Python - print total cost

Tags: python, python-2.7, bin-packing, pulp

I'm working on a bin packing problem based on this code [Bin packing Python query with variable bin cost and sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450533/bin-packing-python-query-with-variable-bin-cost-and-sizes)

How do I print the total cost of the solution? i.e. "4 bins used, cost = 50"

So far I have

```
for i in range(max_bins):
     if y[i].value() == 1:
          print 'bin used = cost', bincost[i]
```

This prints the cost of each used bin which is great but I would like the total cost. So I added

```
print sum(bincost[i])
```

However, when I use this I get the error `"'float' object is not iterable"`. Does anyone have any suggestions of another way to approach this?

Comment: What is your entire code? What is bincost?

Comment: bincost is a list of floats e.g. [48.0, 36.0, 60.0, 60.0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find the sum of a float. This is not possible. It seems that you need to do `print sum([bincost[i] for i in range(len(bincost)) if y[i].value() == 1])`

Comment: This prints the sum of all of the bins, I only want to print the sum of the bins that were used.

Comment: @plshelp How about now

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. I've found another way too by changing the floats to ints and then appending them to a list and then finding the sum.